# R ifelse vs if else vs for loop - datediff excluding weekends

Tags: r, datediff, weekend

I am trying to calculate whether or not a person canceled their appointment within the proper timeframe. I am confident there is a cleaner way to do this, and I am open to suggestions, but this is where I am now.

I have calculated the day of the week of the appointment and I have calculated the difference between that appointment date and the cancel date. If appt is on a Monday and I want to subtract 2 from the corresponding datediff value. Otherwise do nothing.

I tried doing it using ifelse but I can't seem to figure out how to make that compute something when the result is TRUE, only display values.

I am thinking something along the lines of

```
If (df7$weekday =='Monday') {
df7$cancel_lead_time - 2
}
```

P.S. For anyone wondering I am going to tackle holidays after I solve this

Comment: Provide example input and expected output, I am guessing you just need `df7$cancel_lead_time <- ifelse(df7$weekday =='Monday', df7$cancel_lead_time - 2, df7$cancel_lead_time)`

Comment: @zx8754 This is also exactly what I was trying to accomplish, was really overthinking the operator part and trying all kinds of brackets. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I've understood properly; is this what you're trying to do?

```
if(df7$weekday == 'Monday') {
  df7$cancel_lead_time - 2
} else {
  df7$cancel_lead_time
}
```

Comment: yes this is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. I was forgetting to define the else properly. Thank you!

Comment: @RetepYarrum no, you need `ifelse`, not `if() else`.